# golang1.4 http server keep idle connection

Tags: http, go

Is there a way to keep idle connection open after a specified timeout at the server side?

I have a http server implemented using golang1.4 and an API will respond after 10 seconds. While I set `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` at the client (using golang1.4), I still get the `read tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:xx: use of closed network connection`. I think it may be caused by server closing the idle connection.

I found [GOLANG, HTTP having “use of closed network connection” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385487/golang-http-having-use-of-closed-network-connection-error) and [http.Server: timeout for idle connections only?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/C70r06L8Qr4), but they didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

At the server side, set `ReadTimeout` may help.

Ref: [Creating an idle timeout in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334407/creating-an-idle-timeout-in-go)